# Populate multi select from localstorage array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following array.

```json
[
  {
    "costprice": "12.00",
    "costpricemarker": "12.00",
    "discount": 0,
    "itemName": "Cheese cake",
    "itemid": "812",
    "price": "22.00",
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "costprice": "12.00",
    "costpricemarker": "12.00",
    "discount": 0,
    "itemName": "Milo",
    "itemid": "811",
    "price": "22.00",
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "costprice": "12.00",
    "costpricemarker": "12.00",
    "discount": 0,
    "itemName": "Orange Juice",
    "itemid": "809",
    "price": "22.00",
    "quantity": 2
  }
]
```

The first select is populated with the following code:

```js
var tableItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('item'));
for (var i = 0; i < tableItems.length; i++) {
  $('#sbOne').append('<option value=\'' + tableItems[i] + '\'>' +
    tableItems[i]['itemName'] + '</option>');
  if (tableItems[i]['itemName'] >) {
    $('#sbOne').append('<option value=\'' + tableItems[i] + '\'>' +
      tableItems[i]['itemName'] + '</option>');
  }
}
```

This results in Cheese cake, Milo, Orange Juice in the multiselect. However since Orange Juice and Milo have quantity 2 I want my result to be Cheese cake, Milo, Milo,  Orange Juice, Orange Juice

What I tried:

```js
for (var i=0 ;i<tableItems.length; i++) {
  $("#sbOne").append("<option value='" + tableItems[i] + "'>" +
    tableItems[i]['itemName'] + "</option>");
  if (tableItems[i]['quantity'] >1) {
    $("#sbOne").append("<option value='" + tableItems[i] + "'>" +
      tableItems[i]['itemName'] + "</option>");
  }
}
```

This is not not working as I want, how to append all items by taking into account the quantity.

Comment: You can just use another `for` loop and set it to loop over the `quantity` of the `tableItems[i]`: `for (var j=0; j<tableItems[i]['quantity']; j++) { $("#sbOne").append("<option value='" + tableItems[i] + "'>" + tableItems[i]['itemName'] + "</option>"); }`

Comment: You're missing something after `>` in `if (tableItems[i]['itemName'] >)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var tableItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('item'));

for (var i=0 ;i<tableItems.length; i++) {
            quantity  = tableItems[i]["quantity"]
            for (var x=0; x<quantity ; x++) {
                 //do your appending here ....
                $("#sbOne").append("<option value='" + tableItems[i] + "'>" + tableItems[i]['itemName'] + "</option>")
            }
}
```

You may need to adjust the actual appending line since I'm not totally familiar with the context of the element you are appending too...

Comment: thank you, the proposed way in the comment is also working but since your solution would require fewer code I would prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can simplify your code and use innerHTML to inject the HTML once.

```js
const tableItems = [
  {
    "costprice": "12.00",
    "costpricemarker": "12.00",
    "discount": 0,
    "itemName": "Cheese cake",
    "itemid": "812",
    "price": "22.00",
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "costprice": "12.00",
    "costpricemarker": "12.00",
    "discount": 0,
    "itemName": "Milo",
    "itemid": "811",
    "price": "22.00",
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "costprice": "12.00",
    "costpricemarker": "12.00",
    "discount": 0,
    "itemName": "Orange Juice",
    "itemid": "809",
    "price": "22.00",
    "quantity": 2
  }
];

document.getElementById("sbOne").innerHTML += tableItems.map(item => {
    const html = [];
  let qty = item.quantity;
  while (qty-- > 0) {
    html.push(`<option value="${item.itemid}">${item.itemName}</option>`);
  }
  return html.join("");
 }).join("");
```

```html
<select id="sbOne">

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned you can do this with a nested for loop,
or you can do it with a simple line (also to manipulate the DOM only once after preparing all items)

```
    const itemsHTML = tableItems.map(item => 
        Array(item.quantity).fill("<option value='" + item.itemid + "'>" + item.itemName + "</option>").join('')
    ).join('');
    $("#sbOne").append(itemsHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this line of yours:

```
"<option value='" + tableItems[i] + "'>"
```

results in this:

```html
<option value="[object Object]">
```

`[object Object]` is not at all useful.

You probably intended this:

```
"<option value='" + JSON.stringify(tableItems[i]) + "'>"
```

which will store the item as JSON string into the `<object>` value:

```html
<option value="{" costprice":"12.00","costpricemarker":"12.00","discount":0,"itemname":"orange="" juice","itemid":"809","price":"22.00","quantity":2}"="">Orange Juice</option>
```

Here's a version of your code that uses some ES6 features:

```js
const tableItems = [
  {
    "costprice": "12.00",
    "costpricemarker": "12.00",
    "discount": 0,
    "itemName": "Cheese cake",
    "itemid": "812",
    "price": "22.00",
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "costprice": "12.00",
    "costpricemarker": "12.00",
    "discount": 0,
    "itemName": "Milo",
    "itemid": "811",
    "price": "22.00",
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "costprice": "12.00",
    "costpricemarker": "12.00",
    "discount": 0,
    "itemName": "Orange Juice",
    "itemid": "809",
    "price": "22.00",
    "quantity": 2
  }
];

let mySelect = $("#mySelect");

// create all the select content
const selectContent = tableItems.reduce((acc, el) => {

  const {itemName, quantity} = el;
  
  // create `quantity` number of <option> elements
  for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    acc += `
    <option value="${JSON.stringify(el)}">${itemName}</option>`;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

// add content to select
mySelect.empty();
mySelect.append(selectContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect" multiple="true" size="5"></select>
```